# Allow other specific domains to write to our Callable Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We are building a project where we would like to allow any other website to write data to *our own* (single) project in Firebase.

It is hard to understand if possible and how to :

1. Allow any domain `xyz` to include our JS library, and then use a `callable` Function, or just a normal http `onRequest` `Function` in this library to write to *our own* Firestore DB from his domain.( so we initialize our own `App` in this JS)
2. **Safely** confirm the sender website/domain on the Function, so for example i can make a condition in the Function that check if xyz is the ***real*** domain which is writing now (which the request comes from) and then check if we allow this specific domain to write and where to write(using `Rules`).

Is such a "system" possible in Firebase with this or any other constellation?
If so - how do you authenticate a domain in a `Callable` function, and allow any domain to write.

Comment: You can use cors to whitelist the domains

Comment: can you be sure that nobody can "fake" writing from a different domain? can a Function be sure that the request comes from a certain domain ?

Comment: It will work properly till someone use Postman.

Comment: so is there a way to identify a request from a certain domain somehow ?

Comment: what do you mean by "real" domain?